# Splitting data into two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to create a table with this info:

```
ID bigint(20) PK AI
FID bigint(20) unique
points int(10) index 
birthday date index 
current_city varchar(175) index 
current_country varchar(100) index 
home_city varchar(175) index 
home_country varchar(100) index 
Engine = MyISAM
```

On school I learned: create 2 extra tables, one with **cities** and one with **countries** and FK to that table when inserting data. The reason I doubt is:

This table will have around **10M** inserts an hour. I'm afraid if I Insert a row and have to lookup the city FK and country FK every insert, I might lose a lot of speed? And is this worth the gain I get when I am selecting rows which only happens with WHERE ID = id. there will be around **25M** of those selects an hour.

Comment: Thanks for editing, as you see I am quite new to stackoverflow as well :)

Comment: I'd say to do it. The benefits of having a foreign keys to maintain your integrity and improve queries will outweigh the slight overhead on inserts and updates. Inserts are pretty fast regardless, and I doubt the impact of the insert overhead will be noticeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Premature optimization if the root of all evil. Design cleanly first, and optimize next, when you have actual performance data.

A clean design would be a properly normalized table, i.e. with separate city and a country tables.

> I'm afraid if I Insert a row and have to lookup the city FK and country FK every insert, I might lose a lot of speed?

Actually, inserting just small IDs instead of raw country/city names in a varchar column may be more efficient:

- This will result in less disk writes
- You have a **MyISAM** table; so it doesn't have FK support, and **doesn't do any foreign key lookup / check**
- Replacing the varchar columns with integers will put the table in **[fixed-length rows format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/static-format.html)**, which may be faster than the dynamic length format

Benchmark with real data/workload, and see if de-normalizing is really worth it.

Comment: I see your points, I am quite new with MySQL and PHP (used to program in C#), thanks a lot for the info. The no FK lookup check is of course worse of integrity but will be faster when inserting?

Answer (score 1):

There's a reason why db normalization exists.
Use a table for cities, one for countries and join them with your master table via FK's.
Also, what country do you know having 100 chars in the name?
What city do you know having 175 chars in the name?
ID can be bigint, but are you sure you need a BIGINT(20), wouldn't a INT(11) suffice ? Anyway, `AUTOINCREMENT` it and don't `UNIQUE` it, it doesn't make any sense.
Also, you have indexes on every column, but no composite index. This is wrong for so many reasons. Do not `pre-index`, but index depending on your queries. Use `explain` to see what's to be indexed.
Also, don't be afraid to use composite indexes and avoid creating indexes for every column that you have.
Do all the above steps and you will have fast queries (let's hope at least)

Comment: Twisted, thanks a lot for your answer, what means composite index, are that indexes on multiple columns at once? Sorry I am quite new to Databases and PHP.

Comment: 167 is biggest city name and 86 is biggest country name btw.

Comment: @KevinVermaat - ok, i didn't know about country/city name with that length, good to know. Yes, composite index means one index on multiple columns, i.e: `select username from users where a=1 and b=2` would result in a composite index `ab` on column `a` and column `b`.

Answer (score 1):

The City and Country tables will be small (relatively) and probably fit nice in memory so lookups will be fast.

If that isn't fast enough try to cache the lookup client side (ie your php-app).

Since your rows will be smaller (int instead of varchar) you can fit more rows on each page making index lookups faster.

Try to do it normalized first, it will probably be fast enough.

And make sure you use InnoDB instead of MyISAM. It has much better locking and your application looks very concurrent.

Comment: Thanks, I did create the new structure and it has even better performance. But are you sure about the innodb? I use a lot of count queries, which is very slow in innoDB, since they are full-table scans. I believe you if you say InnoDB is better for my application, but is there a way I can cope with the count(*) queries?

Comment: This is not the place to go into details but you are correct that MyISAM has faster count(*) queries. If you do any kind of concurrent writes/reads (as opposed to pure reads) the table locking in MyISAM will quickly limit your throughput. If you do only reads MyISAM might be better. When it comes to count(*) against InnoDB it is possible to maintain a table count with triggers but that might be worse than MyISAM.

Comment: Okay thanks again @Andreas. Well I do reads/writes at the same time, but I have the feeling that my shared webhost has much better performance with MyISAM, is this possible? When I do 1M inserts with MyISAM it takes 8 minutes, with InnoDB it takes almost 35 minutes. Because of this I use MyISAM.